# Daisy chained CloudFront with Host header forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm experimenting with using CloudFront as a simple reverse proxy to allow for custom domains for a web application I'm building. I have the following domains:

- *example.com* (my application behind an ALB)
- *reseller.com* (CloudFront distro pointing to origin: *example.com*)
- *customer.com* (CloudFront distro pointing to origin: *reseller.com*)

This scenario works fine and I see *reseller.com* as the Host on my app:

> *reseller.com* (forward host header) -> *example.com*

This scenario works fine, but not ideal because I see *reseller.com* as the host on my app instead of *customer.com* because the host header wasn't forwarded:

> *customer.com* (not forwarding host header) -> *reseller.com* (forward host header) -> *example.com*

This scenario results in CloudFront throwing a 403:

> *customer.com* (forward host header) -> *reseller.com* (forward host header) -> *example.com*

Why does the forwarding the host header from one CloudFront to another CloudFront distro throw a 403?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366809/api-gateway-and-regional-custom-domain-as-cloudfront-origin

Comment: TL;DR, CloudFront normally needs SNI to work. Forwarding `Host` header causes CF not able to negotiate SSL handshake.

Comment: @jellycsc SSL fails will cause 502

Comment: travis is getting 403 , I suspect this is because of loop. do you know if both customer.com and reseller.com are pointed to CloudFront IP addresses ? This will cause a loop because customer.com will connect to reseller.com (with host header as customer.com) and if reseller.com is again pointed to CloudFront IP, CloudFront will match distribution on host header or based on the SNI in client hello. with reseller resolving to cloudfront IP and with host header as customer.com will match it again to the same distribution and after 3 via headers , request will be dropped with 403.

Comment: why don't have simply have 1 cloudfront distribution with both customer.com and reseller.com added to it and origin as example.com and forward host header.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your ALB (Application Load Balancer) also uses CloudFront.

AWS only allows a **maximum of 2 CloudFront distributions in the daisy chain of requests from server to its source files**, shown in the “Via” line below.

AWS will return a 403 for any more than 2 CloudFront distributions.

To see how many CloudFront distributions are in your chain of requests, use `curl -v` on your domain.

This has 3 (returns 403):

```
curl -v customer.com
...
< Via: 1.1 blah1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 blah2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 blah3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

This has 2 (no 403):

```
curl -v reseller.com
...
< Via: 1.1 blah2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 blah3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

Either switch to a different CDN (not CloudFront) or find a way to avoid 3 CloudFronts in your chain.

I can't find any AWS documentation on this, but it's what AWS technical support told me. We saw a similar problem at my company.